# How can WhatsApp show me an image/video if I didn't download it to phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, thumbnails

If I send an image/video via WhatsApp and the other person doesn't download it, how can he still see the image as a blurry image?

From looking through the app's database, I found out that the local path of the image that was downloaded is located in the `thumb_image` column in the `messages` table. However, if the image is not downloaded, I don't have any information about the local path.

Does WhatsApp store that image as temporary image data on the device?

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnails are stored in WhatsApp's database as `BLOB` in the `message_thumbnails` table, under `thumbnail` column.